# How do I open Photoshop projects in Illustrator using Applescript?

Tags: scripting, applescript

I'm trying to write a script that takes multiple projects I have edited in photoshop and opens them in Illustrator, makes some changes, saves it a bunch of different ways, and then closes the project and opens the next one. I have everything working except opening the photoshop files in Illustrator. All the projects will be located in the same folder so I tried setting all those files to a list using the finder and then in illustrator opening the file. Here is the code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of folder POSIX file "/Volumes/Assets/BLG.com Images/Images for Renaming/Photoshop Files" as list
end tell
repeat with f in theFiles
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
        activate
        open f with options {class:Photoshop options, preserve hidden layers:true, preserve layers:true} without dialogs
        set allLayers to layers of document 1
        set allImages to page items of document 1
        repeat with lay in allLayers
            set visible of lay to true
        end repeat
        repeat with img in allImages
            set scaleMatrix to get scale matrix horizontal scale 416 vertical scale 416
            transform img using scaleMatrix
        end repeat
        selectobjectsonactiveartboard document 1
        delay 2
        do script "Fit Artboard to Selected" from "Fit Artboard"
        set visible of layer 2 of document 1 to false
        set visible of layer 4 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Raw Copper Save" from "RC"
        set visible of layer 5 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Architectural Copper Save" from "AR"
        set visible of layer 6 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Satin Antique Save" from "SA"
        set visible of layer 7 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Brushed Nickel Save" from "BN"
        set visible of layer 8 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Polished Nickel Save" from "PN"
        set visible of layer 10 of document 1 to false
        set visible of layer 9 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Antique Copper Save" from "AC"
        set visible of layer 11 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Verdigris Patina Save" from "VG"
        set visible of layer 12 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Satin Verdigris Patina Save" from "SV"
        set visible of layer 13 of document 1 to false
        set visible of layer 2 of document 1 to true
        delay 2
        do script "Black Save" from "BK"
        set visible of layer 14 of document 1 to false
        set visible of layer 2 of document 1 to false
        set visible of layer 15 of document 1 to false
        delay 2
        do script "Default Save" from "Default"
        delay 2
        save document 1 in "/Volumes/Assets/BLG.com Images/Images for Renaming/Illustrator Files" as Illustrator
        delay 2
        close document 1
    end tell
end repeat
```

Currently this code opens the file in photoshop and not in Illustrator which really confuses me since I'm telling the Illustrator application to open it, not the finder. Any insight here would be much appreciated. Been banging my head against my desk trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last try

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of folder "Assets:BLG.com Images:Images for Renaming:Photoshop Files" as alias list
end tell
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    set user interaction level to never interact
    activate
    set photoshopOptions to {class:Photoshop options, preserve layers:true, preserve hidden layers:true}
    set IllustratorPreferences to {class:Illustrator preferences, Photoshop file options:photoshopOptions}
end tell
repeat with f in theFiles
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
        open f without dialogs
        set allLayers to layers of document 1

 …
```

Comment: Import options still popped up. I find it hard to believe that there isn't some way to automate that but I guess it is possible it is something that you have to click. Thanks for the help though! Very much appreciated!

Comment: Never mind this does work! Just make sure to do a hard restart on Illustrator so the preference changes take place.

Answer (score 1):

does this work

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of folder "Assets:BLG.com Images:Images for Renaming:Photoshop Files" as alias list
end tell
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    activate
    tell Photoshop file options of settings
        set preserve hidden layers to true
        set preserve layers to true
    end tell
end tell
repeat with f in theFiles
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
        open f without dialogs
        set allLayers to layers of document 1
…
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the Finder to open a document with a specific application.
Please try this (keep the open line commented out)

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of folder "Assets:BLG.com Images:Images for Renaming:Photoshop Files"
end tell
activate application "Adobe Illustrator"
repeat with f in theFiles
    tell application "Finder" to open f using application file id "com.adobe.illustrator"
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"

        -- open f with options {class:Photoshop options, preserve hidden layers:true, preserve layers:true} without dialogs
        set allLayers to layers of document 1
…
```

Comment: This opens the file in illustrator, but the reason I was using that open command the way I was is because I need to preserve layers across the programs and those are the options I need. I want it to run without giving me that popup when opening every file because I don't want to have to babysit this script while it is running